# Counting lines from a string

Tags: python, count, split

I need to create a program which removes punctuation, some specific words, duplicates and return the words left and their respective lines. I also need to keep track of the duplicates. For instance,

*Python IDLE*
Indexer: type in lines, finish with a . at start of line only
It is a briskly blowing wind that blows
from the north, the North of my youth.
The wind is cold too, colder than the
winds of yesteryear.
.
The index is:
brisk 1
blow 1
wind 1, 3, 4
north 2
youth 2
cold 3
yesteryear 4

The Problem: I need to keep track of the line number of the words left and also their duplicates. I'm not being able to do that.

```
from string import *

stopWords = [ "a", "i", "it", "am", "at", "on", "in", "to", "too", "very", \

              "of", "from", "here", "even", "the", "but", "and", "is", "my", \

              "them", "then", "this", "that", "than", "though", "so", "are" ]

endings = [ "es" , "ed" , "er", "ly"]

punctuation = [ ".", "," , ":" , ";" , "!" , "?" , "&" , "'" ]

unindexed_sentence = raw_input("type in lines, finish with a . at start of line only").lower()

#removing duplicates.
def unique_string(l):
    ulist = []
    ulist2 = []
    [ulist.append(x) for x in l if x not in ulist]
    [ulist2.append(x)]
    global ulist2

    return ulist
unindexed_sentence =' '.join(unique_string(unindexed_sentence.split()))

unindexed_sentence1 = split(unindexed_sentence,"\n")

list_unindexed = []



# splitting 
i = 0
while i<len(unindexed_sentence1):
    list_unindexed += [split(unindexed_sentence1[i])] 
    i+=1
countline = 0
i = 0
while i < len(list_unindexed):
    j = 0
    while j < len(list_unindexed[i]):
        if list_unindexed[i][j][0] in punctuation:
            list_unindexed[i][j] = list_unindexed[i][j][:0]
        if list_unindexed[i][j][-1] in punctuation:
            list_unindexed[i][j] = list_unindexed[i][j][:-1]
        if list_unindexed[i][j][-1] == "s":
            list_unindexed[i][j] = list_unindexed[i][j][:-1]
        if list_unindexed[i][j][-2:] in endings:
            list_unindexed[i][j] = list_unindexed[i][j][:-2]
        if list_unindexed[i][j][-3:] == "ing":
            list_unindexed[i][j] = list_unindexed[i][j][:-3]
        if list_unindexed[i][j] in stopWords:
            del list_unindexed[i][j]

        else:
            j += 1
    i += 1
    countline += 1

def new_line(n):
    split(n,"\n")
    count = 1
    if n[-1] == "\n":
        count += 1
    return count

string1 = str(list_unindexed)

string2 = str(string1)

string2 ='\n'.join(unique_string(string2.split()))   

print string2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it your homework?

Here some tips:

- Don't do: `from string import *`. You don't need it.
- Use `data.splitlines()` to get list of lines
- Use `enumerate()` to get a index, e.g.: `for i, line in enumerate(data.splitlines())`
- Use a dictionary for keeping track of all words. Each value could be a list or a set of line numbers
- Don't remove duplicates initially. You can do this using dictionaries or sets.